# How to use mix-blend-mode on focus outline based on background?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `mix-blend-mode` to change the focus outline when the background is the same color as the focus outline color. I'm having trouble putting it all together.

When the background is blue, then the focus outline should be white, which it is. But, when the background is white, I want the focus outline to be blue, which it is not.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach((element) => {
  element.setAttribute("href", "#");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button::after {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

button:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible::after,
input[type=checkbox]:focus-visible,
input[type=radio]:focus-visible,
input[type=submit] {
  outline: 2px solid white;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">a button</a>
  <h4><a href="#">Inline text element</a></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue need use `css` property `isolation: isolate` on the parent element.  In that case we create a new stacking context and apply `mix-blend-mode`. [about isolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation)

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  const body = ev.target.closest('body');
  body.classList.toggle('reverse');
});
document.querySelectorAll('a:not(a[href])').forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('href', '#');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-clr: white;
  --secondary-clr: blue;
}

.reverse {
  --primary-clr: blue;
  --secondary-clr: white;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--secondary-clr);
  isolation: isolate;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--primary-clr);
}

.button {
  background: grey;
  color: var(--primary-clr);
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button::after {
  outline: 1px solid var(--primary-clr);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

button:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible,
a:focus-visible::after,
input[type='checkbox']:focus-visible,
input[type='radio']:focus-visible,
input[type='submit'] {
  outline: 2px solid var(--primary-clr);
  outline-offset: 4px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">click to change</a>
  <h4><a href="#">Inline text element</a></h4>
</div>
```